# unable to connect instance on port 22

Tags: google-compute-engine

On google compute engine, yesterday on September 13, at 4 PM, I did an image of my boot disk.

Today, on September 14, I made some changes on /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to change from port 22 to other port.

After that, for some unknown reason, I was unable to connect on my instance. So I have deleted the instance and I re-created it from my boot disk image done yesterday.

And now when I try to connect on my instance, I have again the message : unable to connect on port 22.

How is it possible?
Because yesterday when I did the boot disk image, port 22 has not been changed.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks for your help
Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can forget my post.
I used the wrong image and firewall rules were not up to date.

thanks